# How can I plot a histogram with variable bin widths in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have found the function `dhist()` in the `ggplot2` package that implements the variable width histogram described by [Denby and Mallows (2009)](http://pubs.amstat.org/doi/pdf/10.1198/jcgs.2009.0002) but I can not find any examples of its use. I would like to use it with the following code to create 
variable bin widths:

```
x1 <- c(rep(0, 250), rlnorm (1000)) 
x2 <- c(rlnorm(1250)) 
x <- data.frame(x1, x2) 
x.long <- melt(x, measure.vars=c("x1","x2")) 
ggplot(x.long, aes(x=value)) + 
 geom_step(aes(x=value, y=..density.., colour=variable), 
   stat="bin", binwidth=0.2) + 
 coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-1, 15))
```

How can I do this?

*note:* I cross posted this question from the [ggplot2 google group](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_frm/thread/ddf9406764f4b3df) where it has been unanswered. If I get an answer here, will post there, and vice versa

Comment: Perhaps you want to tell us in which package dhist() can be found?

Comment: @Andrie `ggplot2`, thanks for pointing out my oversight; I have updated my post

Comment: Which version of ggplot2 are you using? I have 0.8.9 and it isn't there...

Comment: @lselzer, I am using version 0.8.8

Comment: You can use the breaks argument to `stat_bin`/`geom_histogram`

Comment: @hadley I've been working on this, but I still can't figure out 1) how to keep just the outline and 2) how to get dhist to calculate breaks for x1 and x2 separately

Comment: You'll need to do the calculation outside of ggplot2 - there's probably not a terribly easy way to do this at the moment, but that's something I want to remedy with my unreleased [densityVis](https://github.com/hadley/densityvis) package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, thanks to a hint from Hadley and a lot of trial and error. I also changed the data and number of bins (`nbins`) so that the effect would be more noticeable.

```
library(ggplot2) #using version 0.8.8
x1 <- c(rnorm(100,8,4), rnorm(100, 2,2), rnorm(100,0,10))
x2 <- c(rlnorm(1000),rnorm(1000,1,10), rep(1,500), rep(5,500))
ggplot() + 
  geom_step(aes(x1, y =..density..),
            stat = 'bin',breaks = dhist(x1, nbins =20),
            position = "dodge", color = 'red') +
  geom_step(aes(x2, y =..density..),
            stat = 'bin',breaks = dhist(x2,nbins=20),
            position = "dodge", color = 'blue')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly provide `x` values to geom_step.

```
t <- seq_len(1250) #your x coords, choose something more interesting
x <- data.frame(t, x1, x2)  #notice 
x.long <- melt(x, measure.vars=c("x1","x2")) 

ggplot(x.long) + 
  geom_step(aes(x=t, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-1, 15))
```

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, it gets me started, but dhist returns a variable number of bins, default is 10, so the second line of your code throws an error unless length(t) == length(x1). also I want y to be the density of x, I am not sure if your code does this