# Histograms with variable size binwidth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have the following data

```
 dati <- read.table(text="
        class     num
    1     0.0   63530
    2     2.5   27061
    3     3.5   29938
    4     4.5   33076
    5     5.6   45759
    6     6.5   72794
    7     8.0  153177
    8    10.8  362124
    9    13.5  551051
    10   15.5  198634
  ")
```

And I want to produce a histogram with variable size bins, so that the **area** of each bar reflects the total numerosity (num) of each bin. I tried

```
bins <- c(0,4,8,11,16)
p <- ggplot(dati) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=class,weight=num),breaks = bins)
```

however, this produces a histogram where the **length** of each bar is equal to total numerosity of each bin. Because bin widths are variable, areas are not proportional to numerosity.
I could not solve this apparently easy problem within **ggplot2**. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6):

I *think* you are looking for a density plot - [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515958/how-can-i-plot-a-histogram-with-variable-bin-widths-in-ggplot) has most of the answer. You call `y = ..density..` in `geom_histogram()`.

This works because `stat_bin` (recall `geom_histogram()` is `geom_bar()` + `stat_bin()`, and `stat_bin()` constructs a data frame with columns `count` and `density`. Thus calling `y = ..density..` pulls the right column for density, whereas the default (counts) is as if you call `y = ..count..`.

```
##OP's code
ggplot(dati) +  geom_histogram(aes(x=class, weight=num),
 breaks = bins)
```

[image: Count Histogram]

```
##new code (density plot)
ggplot(dati) +  geom_histogram( aes(x=class,y = ..density.., weight=num),
 breaks = bins, position = "identity")
```

[image: Density Histogram]

You can find some further examples in the [online ggplot2 help page](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_histogram.html) for `geom_histogram()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is more or less what I was looking for. However, because I need to compare different populations, I would like that the total area equal the total numerosity of the population rather than one.  Is it possible to scale the histogram?

Comment: Possibly by setting `y = ..density.. * sum(..count..)`, but I hesitate to give that answer because it sounds like there may be a better way to do what you're looking for. A new question illustrating your desired output might give you a better method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I posted [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397894/multiple-histograms-with-variable-size-binwidth-in-ggplot2), in which I explain in detail what I need to do

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you asking for how to produce variable sized bar widths.  If so, you just need to call the 'width' parameter in your ggplot aesthetics like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, width = num))
```

this method is discussed more in the following question:
[Variable width bars in ggplot2 barplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948604/variable-width-bars-in-ggplot2-barplot-in-r)